# Не видит экземпляр класса

Tags: c#

У меня есть `internal class InlineKB` в котором есть публичная переменная

Создаю в другом классе модификатором `internal` экземпляр класса `InlineKB k = new InlineKB();`
но обратиться к той переменной не могу... Что я делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы объявили приватное поле внутри класса. Доступ к нему можно получить только внутри метода / свойства / конструктора / индексатора (и т.д.) этого класса

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, Благодарю! Буду знать...

Answer (score 2):

Вы должны обращаться к переменной внутри метода.